# How to disable FlipView keyboard keypress without disabling it on child control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

The story, I use MahApps.Metro FlipView inside my window, the FlipView contain a GridView inside, this is working perfectly, but I have one problem, I can't use keyboard arrow to navigate through GridView cell, the `Up` and `Down` arrow is working, but not the `Left` and `Right` arrow, when I press it the flipview change the page.

I try to handle the OnPreviewKeyPress like this,

```
private void FlipView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

but then the GridView also do not receive the keypress.

Comment: I really want to know the solution for this problem too, I experienced a few months ago, I serach for it everywhere, but in the end I gave up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with attempting to handle `PreviewKeyDown`. The trick is, you need to manually fire the `KeyDown` event of the `DataGrid`.

Here's an implementation that works for my test case:

```
private void UIElement_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = FlipView.SelectedItem as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid == null) return; // the selected item is not a DataGrid
    if (!dataGrid.SelectedCells.Any()) return; // no selected cells to move between
    // create a new event args to send to the DataGrid
    var args = new KeyEventArgs(
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
        0,
        e.Key);
    args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; // get the event
    dataGrid.RaiseEvent(args); // raise the event
    e.Handled = true; // prevent the FlipView from going forward/backward
}
```

**Assumption:** You only want to suppress the ability to move the `FlipView` forward/backward when (1) the selected item is a `DataGrid` and (2) the `DataGrid` has one or more selected cells. (Otherwise, you want the arrow keys to work as they normally would.)

---

### Here's the complete code for my test case:

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Items = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Id = 1, Name = "First" },
                new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Second" },
                new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Third" },
                new Item { Id = 4, Name = "Fourth" },
            };
        }

        private void UIElement_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataGrid = FlipView.SelectedItem as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid == null) return;
            if (!dataGrid.SelectedCells.Any()) return;
            var args = new KeyEventArgs(
                Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
                0,
                e.Key);
            args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
            dataGrid.RaiseEvent(args);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <controls:FlipView x:Name="FlipView"
                       Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"
                       Height="200"
                       IsBannerEnabled="True"
                       PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_PreviewKeyDown">
        <controls:FlipView.Items>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
            <Rectangle Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"
                       Width="50"
                       Height="50"
                       Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"
                       Width="50"
                       Height="50"
                       Fill="Blue" />
        </controls:FlipView.Items>
    </controls:FlipView>
</Window>
```

---

If you'd like the arrows to work if the leftmost or rightmost cell is selected, replace the `PreviewKeyDown` event handler with this:

```
private void UIElement_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = FlipView.SelectedItem as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid == null) return;
    if (!dataGrid.SelectedCells.Any()) return;

    // get the column index of the selected cell
    var columnIndex = dataGrid.SelectedCells.First().Column.DisplayIndex;

    // exit if the selected cell is left/right and the arrow is left/right
    if (columnIndex == 0 && e.Key == Key.Left ||
        columnIndex == dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1 && e.Key == Key.Right) return;

    var args = new KeyEventArgs(
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
        0,
        e.Key);
    args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
    dataGrid.RaiseEvent(args);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Also, the XAML for the `DataGrid` should be have the following properties set to ensure that only one cell can be selected at a time:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Your solution works for me, now I have some problem, I wonder if you want to help me, I have a couple flipview page, every page has 1 gridview, now can you help me, when the cell selected is on the most left or right, I want arrow press make the flipview change page, there is also some focus border on the cell, this border does not appear when not use your code.

Comment: @iha, I edited my answer to allow the page to flip if using the arrow keys when the leftmost or right most cell is selected. I also provided a new XAML snippet to show how you might solve the problem with the focus border.

Comment: the focus border is still visible, by the way, I accept your answer, and will reward the bounty in 10 minutes

Comment: Thanks, @iha! Sorry I couldn't solve the border issue. You might be able to get help if you ask a separate question. Good luck.